# Infinite loop react Js ,use useEffect after i put on parameter with useSelector contains data of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, infinite-loop

i wanna ask about my case using useEffect Hook and put on params with useSelector. i really don't know about this infinite loop after i put on my variables contains useSelector that have bunch of data array from redux. I have intention to put on that variables on parameter useEffect, because i want to directly update data and the data display on the same page.

```js
 // this itemGroup have all of data from getGroup 
 const itemGroup = useSelector(selectGroup);

//this function call get api Data and dispatch to initial state
  const callFunction = () => {
    dispatch(getGroup());
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    callFunction();
    // this console.log getting infinite loop after put on itemGroup as parameter useEffect
    console.log()
  }, [itemGroup]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `callFunction()` add this inside useEffect with empty dependency array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is because you pass your store state as a dependency to useEffect. On updating the store state you are dispatching the action named **callFunction** which might be updating your store state again, which triggers useEffect and useEffect again dispatch **callFunction** which creates a loop.

just pass empty array to useEffect:

`useEffect( () =>{ callFunction() },[])`

Comment: this work but how update direclty on the same page without refresh the page ??

Comment: what do you wanna achive? 
could you please explain me a little bit??